# Como verificar se foi selecionado um arquivo no campo input?

Tags: php, html, arquivo, file-upload

Eu faço uma validação de formulário para garantir que o arquivo que um usuário carregou é do tipo certo. Mas o upload é opcional, então eu quero ignorar a validação se ele não fez o upload de nada e enviou o resto do formulário. Como posso verificar se ele carregou algo ou não no `<input name="file-upload[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" />`?

Meu formulário HTML:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Envie esses arquivos:<br />
  <input name="file-upload[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar arquivos" />
</form>
```

**Como eu valido no *back-end* para ver se ele carregou algo ou não no input para arquivos?**

É com is_uploaded_file()? Ou com isset? Ou com *empty*? Ou tem que verifica o código de erro? Porque mesmo não selecionando vem o array de file-upload vazio.

Comment: Minha dúvida é: você está usando `file-upload[]`, realmente pretende enviar mais de um arquivo?

Comment: ... Mas o upload é opcional. O usuário pode ou não enviar, é uma opção. Talvez ele envie 1 ou mais, talvez não envie nada. Mas a ideia inicial é que sim @WallaceMaxters

Comment: `is_uploaded_file` é para checar se o upload foi enviado e se é um arquivo "malicioso", mas não precisa usar junto com `move_uploaded_file`, internamente o `move_uploaded_file` já faz a mesma checagem que o `is_uploaded_file`. PS: Como o @WallaceMaxters disse, se for apenas um arquivo usar o `[]` é redundante.

Comment: Quero deixar aberto para enviar múltiplos arquivos @GuilhermeNascimento. O que eu quero saber é como eu valido no back-end para ver se ele carregou algo ou não no input para arquivos? Se o input de arquivos tinha algum selecionado ou não.

Comment: @user97816 como eu já disse no meu comentário, o proprio `move_uploaded_file` faz isso sozinho, ele checa se é um arquivo enviado por upload mesmo e verifica se é malicioso (para ambientes unix-like e/ou apache creio eu)

Comment: Eu acho que você esta confundindo validar arquivo de upload com validar o INPUT do upload, o que pode ser duas coisas diferentes. O isset assim como o empty tem a função de validar variaveis e chaves definidas e vazias (respectivamente), acho que vc não quer validar se é upload, vc quer validar é se o form foi preenchido adequadamente, seria isto?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu quero saber se o usuário enviou/selecionou/ escolheu, pelo menos um arquivo no meu formulário. Eu quero que o PHP, me diga se se o usuário enviou/selecionou/ escolheu, pelo menos um arquivo no meu formulário, se o <input name="file-upload[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" /> tem ou não algum arquivo selecionado quando chegar no **back-end**. Não quero AJAX, ou validar o tipo de arquivo enviado, e sim saber se veio algum arquivo, se foi selecionado algum arquivo no input para arquivos.

Comment: @user97816 ja viu a resposta ali em baixo ? isset verifica se foi enviado algum arquivo, o foreach verificando move_uploaded_file responde o resultado do upload

Comment: Desculpem se não fui claro.

Comment: @user97816 você quer que, quando o usuário envie o formulário, verificar se tem algum arquivo enviado, se tem, fazer o upload e verificar se foi enviado, se não tem nenhum arquivo junto, não faz nada, é isso ? tenta ver se a resposta que eu dei resolve, se não resolver avisa pra tentar achar o problema.

Comment: @AnthraxisBR é isso ai :(. Vou ver as respostas

Comment: foi justamente o que eu explique no comentário, o uso é empty ou isset, mas tem mais uns detalhes, vou formular uma resposta

Comment: Tudo bem. É dificil de entrar na minha cabeça, mas to entendendo @GuilhermeNascimento

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O [**`is_uploaded_file`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php) não é usado para isto, ele é usado para checar se algo passado veio por upload, supondo que você tenha criado uma função para por exemplo checa a ultima modificação do arquivo, usando [**`filemtime`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php), mas não pode ser um arquivo de upload, então você faria algo como:

```
function my_file_mtime($input)
{
     if (is_uploaded_file($input)) {
          return false;
     }

     return filemtime($input);
}
```

E o no caso usaria assim:

```
var_dump(my_file_mtime('foo/bar/baz.txt')); // retorna um numero, por exemplo int(10), supondo que o arquivo tenha o peso de 10 bytes

var_dump(my_file_mtime($_FILES['file-upload']['tmp_name'])); //Retorna false
```

isso só estou falando para explicar um uso possível do `is_uploaded_file`, que pela sua duvida, **não é o que você precisa**.

Agora voltando ao problema, o que você quer é verificar se o input do FORM foi preenchido, logo `isset` e/ou `empty` irão atende-lo nisto, isto porque o PHP gera as variaveis conforme a necessidade, no caso `!empty()` vai ser mais pratico, pois além de checar se a **variavel super global** (`$_FILES`) foi gerada ele, ficando assim:

```
if (empty($_FILES['file-upload']['name'])) {
    echo 'Você não selecionou nenhum arquivo';//Aqui você pode trocar por um alert ou customizar como desejar, é um aviso que o usuário provavelmente não selecionou nada
} else {
    $arquivos = $_FILES['file-upload'];
    $total = count($arquivos['name']);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
        //Ação do upload para cada arquivo adicionado com "[]"
    }
}
```

No geral isso já resolve boa parte, inclusive se o usuário selecionou algo, mas ainda sim existe a checagem de erros que é explicado neste link:

> [Error Messages Explained](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

São constantes que você poderá usar para saber qual erro ocorreu ao enviar o arquivo:

- `UPLOAD_ERR_OK` não houve erro, o upload foi bem sucedido.
- `UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE` O arquivo enviado excede o limite definido na diretiva upload_max_filesize do php.ini.
- `UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE` O arquivo excede o limite definido em `MAX_FILE_SIZE` no formulário HTML.
- `UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL` O upload do arquivo foi feito parcialmente.
- `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE` Nenhum arquivo foi enviado.
- `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR` Pasta temporária ausente. Introduzido no PHP 5.0.3.
- `UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE` Falha em escrever o arquivo em disco. Introduzido no PHP 5.1.0.
- `UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION` Uma extensão do PHP interrompeu o upload do arquivo. O PHP não fornece uma maneira de determinar qual extensão causou a interrupção. Examinar a lista das extensões carregadas com o phpinfo() pode ajudar. Introduzido no PHP 5.2.0.

Basta você comparar essas constantes com `$_FILES['file-upload']['error']` e no seu caso como usou `[]`, deve usar assim `$_FILES['file-upload']['error'][$index]` (o `$index` seria o iterador do `for`, é apenas um exemplo, no caso é a mesma coisa que `$i` que usei no exemplo acima)

Um exemplo simples seria checar somente se é diferente de `UPLOAD_ERR_OK`, assim:

```
if (empty($_FILES['file-upload']['name'])) {
    echo 'Você não selecionou nenhum arquivo';//Aqui você pode trocar por um alert ou customizar como desejar, é um aviso que o usuário provavelmente não selecionou nada
} else {
    $arquivos = $_FILES['file-upload'];
    $total = count($arquivos['name']);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
        $nome = $arquivos['name'][$i];

        if ($arquivos['error'][$i] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            echo 'Erro ao fazer upload de ', htmlspecialchars($nome), '<br>';
            continue;
        }

        if (move_uploaded_file($arquivos['tmp_name'][$i], 'pasta/foo/bar/' . $nome)) {
            echo 'O arquivo ', htmlspecialchars($nome),' foi carregado<br>';
        } else {
            echo 'O arquivo ', htmlspecialchars($nome),' não foi carregado<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

Você também pode informar a mensagem de erro detalhada para o usuário:

```
function mensagem_de_erro($code) {
    switch ($code) {
        case UPLOAD_ERR_OK: //Se o upload for OK ele retorna false
            return false;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
            return 'O upload excedeu o limite máximo definido no upload_max_filesize no php.ini';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
            return 'O upload excedeu o MAX_FILE_SIZE especificado no formulário HTML';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL:
            return 'O upload foi parcial';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
            return 'Não foi selecionado um arquivo';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR:
            return 'A pasta temporária não foi definida (php.ini) ou não é acessivel';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE:
            return 'Não pode fazer o upload na pasta temporaria';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION:
            return 'O upload foi interrompido por uma extensão PHP';
        default:
            return 'Erro desconhecido';
    }
}

if (empty($_FILES['file-upload']['name'])) {
    echo 'Você não selecionou nenhum arquivo';//Aqui você pode trocar por um alert ou customizar como desejar, é um aviso que o usuário provavelmente não selecionou nada
} else {
    $arquivos = $_FILES['file-upload'];
    $total = count($arquivos);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
        $nome = $arquivos['name'][$i];

        $erro = mensagem_de_erro($arquivos['error'][$i]);

        if ($erro) {
            echo $erro, ' - arquivo: ', htmlspecialchars($nome), '<br>';
            continue; //Pula o item atual do array para o proximo se algo falha no atual
        }

        if (move_uploaded_file($arquivos['tmp_name'][$i], 'pasta/foo/bar/' . $nome)) {
            echo 'O arquivo ', htmlspecialchars($nome),' foi carregado<br>';
        } else {
            echo 'O arquivo ', htmlspecialchars($nome),' não foi carregado<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1 - Você não vai carregar com o `form`, o `form` vai apenas forçar o envio para algum script `server-side` (PHP) fazer o `upload`, no caso, você receberia no ***PHP*** e faria o colocaria o arquivo em algum lugar com `move_uploaded_file()` (existem outras possiblidades¹):

Exemplo retirado da [documentação oficial](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.file-upload.post-method.php):

```
$uploaddir = '/pasta/para/upload';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file-upload']['name']);


if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fil-eupload']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "Se o arquivo pode ser movido para a pasta informada essa será a resposta.\n";
} else {
    echo "Caso o arquivo não tenha sido carregado para a pasta informada esta a resposta!\n";
}
```

Agora, como você possui `[]` em `file-upload`, significa que pretende enviar mais de um arquivo, segue exemplo adaptado do exemplo anterior:

```
//Diretório para upload
$uploaddir = '/pasta/para/upload';
//Salva os arquivos enviados em uma váriavel $files
$files = $_FILES['file-upload'];

//Inicia um contador (apenas para dizer em qual linha foram as respostas)
$a = 0;
//Verificando se existe algum alguma coisa em $files
if (isset($files)) {

    $name = $files['name'];
    $tmp_name = $files['tmp_name'];
    //Passando um loop por $files
    foreach ($name as $file) {
        //Definindo um diretório para o arquivo ser carregado
        $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($name[$a]);
        //Verificando se o arquivo pode ser carregado
        if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name[$a], $uploadfile)) {
            echo "O arquivo $a foi carregado<br>";
        } else {
            echo "O arquivo $a não foi carregado";
        }
        //Somando ao contador
        $a += 1;
    }
} else {
    echo 'Nenhum arquivo foi enviado';
}
```

¹ - Possibilidades para upload:

[is_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.is-uploaded-file.php)

[move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ftp-put.php)

[ftp_put](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ftp-put.php) - Requer conexão FTP aberta.

Comment: Acho que seria apropriado colocar um if(isset($_FILES['file-upload'])) só pra garantir que existe o índice, já que não é obrigatório!

Comment: Não havia pensado nisso, vou atualizar a resposta.

Comment: Falta um parênteses no isset @AnthraxisBR