# Upload imagens: Mais de um input file com o mesmo nome

Tags: php, laravel-5

Preciso fazer o upload de imagens, mas não posso criar só um *input* e usar o *multiple*, tipo isso:

```
<input type="file" name="images[]" multiple>
```

O que eu preciso é criar 5 *inputs* que no *backend* produzam o mesmo resultado da forma acima.

Tentei criar dois *inputs* com o mesmo *name*, mas não funcionou:

```
<input type="file" name="images[]">
<input type="file" name="images[]">
```

PS: Tem que ser desse jeito, pois assim fica mais fácil para o usuário manipular uma de cada vez.

Codigo PHP:

```
foreach(Input::file('images') as $imagem){
    $destinationPath = 'uploads/' . Auth::user()->loja_id . '/produtos';
    $extension = $imagem->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $fileName = date('YmdHis')
              .microtime(true)
              .rand(111111111, 999999999)
              .'.'
              .$extension;

    $upload_success = $imagem->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
    $image = new ProdutoImagem;
    $image->produto_id = $produto->id;
    $image->imagem = $fileName;
    $image->save();
}
```

Código AJAX.

```
$(document).on('submit', '#form-produto', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: $(this).attr('action'),
                        data: new FormData(this),
                        dataType: 'json',
                        contentType: false,
                        cache: false,
                        processData:false,
                        success: function (data){
                            if(data.status == true){
                                window.location = '/admin/' + data.url;
                            }

                            else{
                                $('.alert span').remove();
                                $('.alert').show();
                                $('.alert').append('<span>' + data.msg + '</span>');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
```

Comment: Qual foi o resultado de `var_dump($_FILES)`?

Comment: array(1) { ["images"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(50) "10888874_794541107285499_3169118019908787459_n.jpg" [1]=> string(17) "3geYt-profile.jpg" } ["type"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" [1]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\php761A.tmp" [1]=> string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\php761B.tmp" } ["error"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(0) [1]=> int(0) } ["size"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(51554) [1]=> int(49193) } } }

Comment: Se foram selecionadas 2 imagens, parece que está correto. Qual o problema?

Comment: Agora eu coloquei só duas imagens para testar. Da erro na hora de percorrer no foreach para cadastrar elas.

Comment: Então deve ser o `foreach` que está errado. Veja a resposta do Guilherme...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A resposta contém exemplo com PHP e com Laravel pois o autor não informou que usava laravel na primeira versão

Como na doc http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.file-upload.multiple.php o uso deve ser assim:

1. para o primeiro arquivo `$_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'][0]`
2. Segundo arquivo `$_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'][1]`

E assim por diante, ou seja vá aumentando o numero a cada arquivo, pode usar o `for ()` que já vai resolver tudo.

Um exemplo:

```
if (empty($_FILES['imagem']['name'])) {
    echo 'Você não selecionou nenhum arquivo';//Aqui você pode trocar por um alert ou customizar como desejar, é um aviso que o usuário provavelmente não selecionou nada
} else {
    $arquivos = $_FILES['imagem'];
    $total = count($arquivos['name']);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
        $nome = $arquivos['name'][$i];

        if ($arquivos['error'][$i] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            echo 'Erro ao fazer upload de ', htmlspecialchars($nome), '<br>';
            continue;
        }

        if (move_uploaded_file($arquivos['tmp_name'][$i], 'pasta/foo/bar/' . $nome)) {
            echo 'O arquivo ', htmlspecialchars($nome),' foi carregado<br>';
        } else {
            echo 'O arquivo ', htmlspecialchars($nome),' não foi carregado<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Extras

É importante lembrar que o form deve conter `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, por exemplo:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
```

Aqui tem um exemplo de como checar outros erros que possam ocorrer no upload https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/256888/3635:

```
function mensagem_de_erro($code) {
    switch ($code) {
        case UPLOAD_ERR_OK: //Se o upload for OK ele retorna false
            return false;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
            return 'O upload excedeu o limite máximo definido no upload_max_filesize no php.ini';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
            return 'O upload excedeu o MAX_FILE_SIZE especificado no formulário HTML';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL:
            return 'O upload foi parcial';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
            return 'Não foi selecionado um arquivo';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR:
            return 'A pasta temporária não foi definida (php.ini) ou não é acessivel';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE:
            return 'Não pode fazer o upload na pasta temporaria';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION:
            return 'O upload foi interrompido por uma extensão PHP';
        default:
            return 'Erro desconhecido';
    }
}
```

O uso deve ser algo assim:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
    $nome = $arquivos['name'][$i];

    $erro = mensagem_de_erro($arquivos['error'][$i]);

    if ($erro) {
        echo $erro, ' - arquivo: ', htmlspecialchars($nome), '<br>';
        continue; //Pula o item atual do array para o proximo se algo falha no atual
    }

    if (move_uploaded_file($arquivos['tmp_name'][$i], 'pasta/foo/bar/' . $nome)) {
        echo 'O arquivo ', htmlspecialchars($nome),' foi carregado<br>';
    } else {
        echo 'O arquivo ', htmlspecialchars($nome),' não foi carregado<br>';
    }
}
```

---

### Se for Laravel

Se for Laravel 5.2:

```
public function metodoDoController(Request $request) {

    if($request->hasFile('attachment')) {

       $files = $request->file('imagem');

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $file->move('foo/bar/pasta');
        }
    }

}
```

Se for Laravel 5.3+ use assim:

```
public function metodoDoController(Request $request) {

    if($request->hasFile('attachment')) {

        $files = $request->file('imagem');

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $file->store('foo/bar/pasta');
        }
    }

}
```

Mais detalhes em https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#files

Comment: Esqueci de mencionar no post que estou usando a sintaxe do Laravel para fazer o upload. E ele usa o seguinte: Input::file('images'). Ja editei o post com o codigo php.

Comment: @DiegoVieira qual versão do Laravel?

Comment: 5.2. Esse código funciona usando apenas com um input com a propriedades multiple. Mas desse jeito não.

Comment: @DiegoVieira editei a resposta

Comment: Estou fazendo isso, só que essa forma da erro quando uso dois inputs file com o mesmo nome. Porem se eu uso apenas um com a propriedade multiple, funciona normal.

Comment: @DiegoVieira que erro? Meu código parece bem diferente do seu na pergunta, tente refazer e observe tudo.

Comment: Agora que eu fui ver, o problema é o ajax. Mandei o form direto pro controller, sem passar pelo ajax e funcionou normal.

Comment: Estranho que o ajax funciona normal do outro jeito usando o multiple

Comment: Poh, mas vc em nenhum momento falou que tava usando Ajax, poxa assim você dificulta tudo, gastei o maior tempo respondendo e o problema era totalmente outra coisa :(

Comment: É que eu nunca imaginei que fosse o ajax dando problema, já que funcionava antes. Coloquei o código no post. Também estou usando a biblioteca jquery mobile.

Comment: Mas é por isso que se vc vai perguntar vc tem que dar detalhes, ajude-nos a ajuda-lo. Siga o MCVE: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Resolvido o problema, retirei o atributo cache: false do ajax.

Comment: @DiegoVieira ah, entendi, mas é estranho o cache: false só deveria funcionar quando fosse GET, para POST o cache nem existe, logo false ou true seria a mesma coisa... Me informa qual a versão do jQuery usou.

Comment: Cara, funcionou uma vez, mas quando fui fazer upload novamente, deu problema. Jquery 1.11.1 e Jquery Mobile 1.4.5

Comment: @DiegoVieira Jquery 1.11.1 é antigo já, provavelmente era um BUG antigo desta versão e já foi corrigido nas novas, mas não se preocupe, cache: false com POST é redundante, seja em qualquer versão, ou seja não precisa usar.

Comment: O problema é que o jquery mobile não funciona nas versões mais recentes do jquery.